# How to check which VARCHAR is larger?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, varchar

I making a number game in which it is a requirement to store very very large numbers. So after some internet searching I came to know the following:

- In a 32-bit memory you can store a number no larger than `2^32-1`. So
  your memory management unit use two registers if the number exceeds
  the max limit. 
  *(Which I've tested by taking on long variable and storing a number larger then `2^32-1`. It was successful.)*

So I thought of a scheme that if number reaches `99999` and it got an increment by `1` so the new number will be `00000a` and then `00001a` up to so on.
As webservice is included in to it so over there I can't use `int` as the type. So I have to use `VARCHAR`. How can I compare that `12345a` is smaller than `12345b`?

Comment: Hi. This is an interesting question.However it's more appropriate for Programmer's Stack Exchange. You're asking 'conceptual' questions whereas stack overflow if specifically for debugging code. Also You've not quite got the idea. I would suggest using raw binary 'BLOB' data under a big integer library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Objective-C, try a `long long int`, I suspect it'll be far easier to manage than messing around with trying to create your own data type.